# Laravel - 'Auth guard [admin] is not defined.'

Tags: laravel

- This is a fresh copy of Laravel 5.6.
- using [spatie laravel permissions.](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

I have maybe altered something while dealing with permissions that could have altered the guard. I have no idea what since I can't see any git changes, maybe via the DB?

At first I tried to tinker and give a specific user admin privileges with:
`$role = Spatie\Permission\Models\Role::where('name', 'admin')->get()->first();`

When that returned undefined, I checked `Auth::guard('admin')`, that returns undefined, so I understand that the issue has nothing to do with Spatie package.

After looking in a few questions/answers here on stackoverflow, one of them being `config:clear` and `config:cache`, which didn't work and still getting undefined for Auth guard admin.

Any other options I could take to get Auth admin?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you edited your `config/auth.php`, e.g. to add another guard and your config is cached, your guards may not be reloaded. If you experience this problem, clearing the config will fix it.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.0/config/auth.php

```
php artisan config:clear OR php artisan config:cache
```

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: You saved my life! haha

Comment: @FacundoFasciolo My pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Add **admin** or **administrator** to the auth guards. After this **php artisan config:clear** can be run to remove the previous cached configurations. It should match your **roles->name** in the database.

*\config\auth.php* (file)

```
'guards' => [
    ...

    'administrator' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

An old question, but stil valid from Laravel 5 to 7